# Generating GridView Headers Automatically from Interface instead of Class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

WPF GridView has `AutoGenerateColumns` that is `true` per default.
This causes the GridView to generate headers based on the class.

I want to use that feature but restrict WPF to properties in an interface instead of the class.

In the minimal example below you can see two Properties. `CanBeSeen` is the one that should be seen. `Other` is the Property that is not part of the Interface and thus should be hidden.

Can this be done?

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Gridly" ItemsSource="{Binding GridlyItemsSource}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public interface IGridlyViewModel
    {
        int CanBeSeen { get; }
    }

    public class ModelData  :IGridlyViewModel
    {
        #region IGridlyViewModel
        public int CanBeSeen { get { return 42; } }
        #endregion
        public int Other { get { return 9001; } }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public IEnumerable<IGridlyViewModel> GridlyItemsSource { get { return new[] { new ModelData() }; } } 

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: DataGrid Output]

Comment: Yes that is possible. You can write an AttachedProperty / Behavior for this specifiying Interface as input, and use reflection. I will do this today. Interesting one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your problem using `Attached Properties`, and `AutoGeneratingColumn` event of `DataGrid`.

In the sample below `WinGrd` is my main window, and I have kept everything in it. You can simple copy paste everything.

Usage :

```
<DataGrid local:WinGrd.FilteringInterface="{x:Type local:IGridlyViewModel}"
          local:WinGrd.ViewModel="{x:Type local:ModelData}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding GridlyItemsSource}" />
```

Code :

```
namespace WpfBinding.Interface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WinGrd.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WinGrd : Window
    {
        public IEnumerable<IGridlyViewModel> GridlyItemsSource { get { return new[] { new ModelData() }; } } 

        public WinGrd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        #region FilteringInterface

        public static Type GetFilteringInterface(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Type)obj.GetValue(FilteringInterfaceProperty);
        }

        public static void SetFilteringInterface(DependencyObject obj, Type value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(FilteringInterfaceProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FilteringInterface.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FilteringInterfaceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FilteringInterface", typeof(Type), typeof(WinGrd), 
                        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(FilteringInterfaceChanged)));

        private static void FilteringInterfaceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dGrid = (DataGrid)d;
            dGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += dGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn;
        }               

        #endregion

        #region ViewModel AttachedProperty

        public static Type GetViewModel(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Type)obj.GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        }

        public static void SetViewModel(DependencyObject obj, Type value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ViewModel.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ViewModel", typeof(Type), typeof(WinGrd), new PropertyMetadata(null));                

        #endregion

        static void dGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

            TypeInfo viewModelTypeInfo = WinGrd.GetViewModel(dGrid).GetTypeInfo();
            Type[] allInterfaces = viewModelTypeInfo.GetInterfaces();

            Type foundInterface = allInterfaces.FirstOrDefault((tp) => { return tp == WinGrd.GetFilteringInterface(dGrid); });

            if (foundInterface == null)
                return;

            TypeInfo foundInterfaceTypeInfo = foundInterface.GetTypeInfo();
            PropertyInfo[] foundInterfaceProps = foundInterfaceTypeInfo.GetProperties();

            if (foundInterfaceProps.FirstOrDefault((p) => { return p.Name == e.PropertyName; }) != null)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " found and used for Column !");
            else
                e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }

    #region Classes

    public interface IGridlyViewModel
    {
        int CanBeSeen { get; }
    }

    public class ModelData : IGridlyViewModel
    {
        #region IGridlyViewModel
        public int CanBeSeen { get { return 42; } }
        #endregion
        public int Other { get { return 9001; } }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that in your case you can't achieve it by just setting ItemsSource to Interface object. It is impossible and reasons for that are quite obvious. AutoGenerateColumns feature is not suitable for your case.
What you can do is to explicitly specify columns. Please see snippet below:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridlyItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CanBeSeen column" Binding="{Binding CanBeSeen }" />     
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```